# pdflatex vs latex + dvipdfm: Line break in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, ieee-style

I like to generate a `pdf` from a `tex`-file. I also require the according `dvi` file.

To generate a `pdf` I usually execute `pdflatex main.tex`. For my current project I get a bibliography like this:
[image]

If I execute `latex main.tex; dvipdfm main.dvi` it looks like this:

[image]

The first image is correct and the second not (the url-line is too long). Therefore probably the `dvi`-file contains already this "wrong" bibliography style.

Is it somehow possible to force this line break in the url in the bibliography and then generate the `dvi` and `pdf` files?

Thank you

Comment: you haven't given many clues as to your input form, presumably latex isn't able to break the hyperlinkss, what options did you give hyperref, in particular did you tell it you were using dvipdfm

Comment: Sorry, I dont know much about this. I just use the standard IEEE template for conference preceedings: https://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.htm . I could not find any additional parameters for hyperref that are used.

Comment: Add the LaTeX source code of the document, *minimized* to the extent which is necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipdfmx}{hyperref}` before \documentclass.

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipdfmx}{hyperref}` works:) Thank you:)!

Comment: Better `\documentclass[dvipdfmx, ...]{...}`. It passes `dvipdfmx` to any package providing this option.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.